# Feathers-Sequelize Where statement and Query param

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I have the following feathers-sequelize query:

```
context.params.sequelize = {
    raw: false,
    include: [{
      model: organisations,
      where: organisationId ? { id: organisationId } : undefined,
      include: [{
        model: roles,
        where: roleId ? { id: roleId } : undefined,
      }],
    }],
    where: single ? (
      sequelize.and(
        sequelize.where(
          sequelize.col('"organisations->organisation_users"."roleId"'),
          sequelize.col('"organisations->roles"."id"'),
        ),
        sequelize.where(
          sequelize.col('"organisations->organisation_users"."userId"'),
          sequelize.col("users.id")
        )
      )
    ) : undefined
  }
```

I make the following service request:

```
await UserService.find({ query: { email: data.email } }))
```

The query object is left out since in the above sequelize query I am setting my own where statement. If I remove the where statement than the query object works. How do I make use of my own where statement and also include the feathers query object?

Thank you & Regards,

Emir

Answer (score 0):

In order to add extra conditions to the existing query object, instead of using the *params.sqeuelize* you **add them directly into the query object** (since it's available throuhg context.params.query) and since you use a before hook, the query object gets modified before the execution. 
In you example should be something like:

```
if(single) {
    context.params.query.push(
      sequelize.and(
        sequelize.where(
          sequelize.col('"organisations->organisation_users"."roleId"'),
          sequelize.col('"organisations->roles"."id"'),
        ),
        sequelize.where(
          sequelize.col('"organisations->organisation_users"."userId"'),
          sequelize.col("users.id")
        )
      )
   )
}
```

Probably not the correct syntax, but that's the idea: add extra conditions directly in the feathers query object. Hope this helps.